# 403 error from 403 ErrorDocument

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403, errordocument

I've the following configuration script in my Apache 2.4.7 installation:

```
<Directory "/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        Require not ip ip.range.A ip.range.B
    </RequireAll>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^faq/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ faq.php?code=$1&num=$2 [NC]
    ErrorDocument 403 /www/faq.php?code=web&num=403
</Directory>
```

And, I'm receiving this error when I try to view a page using one of the blocked IP addresses:

> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Since I want to serve two kinds of 403 to the incoming clients; I've to redirect the users restricted by IP ranges `A` and `B` to be shown the `faq/WEB/403/` page.

Is there some way to block access for users with those IPs and show them my custom `ErrorDocument` page?

I did try using the following instead of the `requireAll` tag (as defined [in the `RewriteCond` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^ip.range.A  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^ip.range.B
RewriteRule /faq/WEB/403/ [L,R]
```

but to no avail. Users were able to access the pages freely in the latter case.

The current configuration file is as follows (and no users are being blocked access to the web pages):

```
<Directory "/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^faq/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ faq.php?code=$1&num=$2 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^ip.range.A  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^ip.range.B
    RewriteRule /faq/WEB/403/ [L,R]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this error :

> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

You're protecting /www directory. As the 403 file is also in this directory it isn't served as access to this content is forbidden to user. You need to put your 403 page in it's own directory which doesn't belong to /www.

On having two separates pages depending on source IP, I'm not sure you can do that with apache config only. `ErrorDocument`are "special" commands which interrupts normal apache flow. A better way would be to do this in PHP or any serverside language.